# Fatal error in MPI_Waitall: Invalid MPI_Request

Tags: fortran, runtime-error, mpi

I bring my code below but when I run it, I encounter with this error:

```
aborting job:
 Fatal error in MPI_Waitall: Invalid MPI_Request, error stack:
 MPI_Wait(171): MPI_Waitall(count=4, req_array=0x000001400E0DE0,status_array = 0x0000000000012FD8C) failed
 MPI_Waitall(96). : Invalid MPI_Request
 MPI_Waitall(96). : Invalid MPI_Request
```

When I’m using a blocking send and receive, my code giving me a correct answer but when I’m using a non blocking send and receive I getting an error.

This is my code :

```
   integer reqs(4)   ! required variable for non-blocking calls 
   integer stats(MPI_status_SIZE,4)   ! required variable for WAITALL routine 


      call MPI_INIT( ierr )
      call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, taskid, ierr )
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numtasks, ierr )

! Send data to the left neighbor
if ((taskid > 0) ) then
call MPI_ISEND(phi0(1,1),N_z,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,taskid-1,11,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&
 reqs(1),ierr)
end if

!  Send data to the right neighbor
if (taskid < numtasks-1) then
call MPI_ISEND(phi0(1,cols),N_z,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,taskid+1,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&
 reqs(2),ierr)
end if

    ! Receives data from the neighbor on the left
if (taskid > 0) then
call MPI_IRECV(phi0(1,0),N_z,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,taskid-1,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&
 reqs(3),ierr)
end if 

    ! From the right side of the neighbors to get the data
if (taskid < numtasks-1) then
call MPI_IRECV(phi0(1,cols+1),N_z,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,taskid+1,11,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&
 reqs(4),ierr)
end if

call MPI_WAITALL(4, reqs, status_array, ierr)
```

Comment: Not all ranks have left or right neighbours, therefore in some of them not all four elements of `reqs` are properly set. Put `reqs = MPI_REQUEST_NULL` somewhere before the conditials in order to initialise all request handles with a value that won't make `MPI_WAITALL` unhappy.

Comment: thanks for your reply @HristoIliev ... but i defined boundary for each send and receive and i don't involve all ranks to send or receive from right side or left ... is it possible that show me in my code to make me understand ?

Comment: Just put `reqs = MPI_REQUEST_NULL` at the start of your program/subroutine.

Comment: thank for reply @HristoIliev ... i do it and error is gone ... but when i run my code, my cpu usage at first is 100% but after a second going to be zero ... i think when its encounter with waitall, going to completely stop and wait for data and data don't transfer ... 
i'll be appreciate if you're tell me where is my problem exactly ?

Comment: can anyone tell me ?